# How to declare a variable depending on if statement in Dart like in Kotlin?

Tags: flutter, variables, kotlin, dart, functional-programming

How to declare a variable depending on if statement in Dart? In Kotlin it would look like this:

```
   val max = if (a > b) {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
```

Is it even possible in Dart?

Comment: yes it is: `var something = bool_expression ? val1 : val2` - check https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more than one statement, we can use a method by declaring its type as int.

```
void main() {
    print(declareVariable());
}

int a = 10;
int b = 30;          

int declareVariable() {
 if(b < a){
   return 1;
 }
 else if(b > a) {
   return 2;
 } 
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**Edited :**

We can declare more then one condition in single line in the same way.

```
var singleLine = b < a ? 1 : b > a ? 2 : 0;
```

This will print out the same answer as method.

Answer (score 8):

@pskink's answer in the comment is correct but it didn't show how you would be able to do it in this scenario. Here is how you can do it in your scenario:

```
final max= a > b ? a : b;
```

The `final` keyword in Dart is the same as the `val` keyword in Kotlin. You will not be able to change the value of the variable. You could also use the `var` keyword in Dart which is the same as Kotlin's `var` keyword. You will be able to change the value of the variable after declaring it. You might be confused with the one-liner code since there isn't any if or else statements inside it. The code above is called a `ternary operator`.
Here is an explanation for it:

```
(condition/expresssion) ? val1(if true execute this) : val2(if false execute this)
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute more than one statement?

Comment: what do you mean with that @AnimeshSahu

Comment: @AnimeshSahu that's not possible with ternary operators. You would have to use if and else statements to do it :( You could do `if(){max=a}else{max=b}` to execute more than one statement.

Comment: Ternary operator is perfect if you have only 2 statements. But I didn't find a way to assign variable without boilerplate when we have 3+ statements. Like here:
`val c = if (a > b) { a } else if (a == b) { 0 } else { b }`